# Add Cppcheck to the Travis CI build

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, travis-ci, cppcheck

I would like to add a Cppcheck scan to my C++ project CI build with Travis CI.

In particular, I need to:

- fail the build if new errors are found
- show the errors in the build result

Comment: This might help you to get started:  https://github.com/hackorama/AnyOption/blob/master/.travis.yml